# Pass bash list into applescript (using osascript)

Tags: bash, applescript

I'm trying to pass a bash list into an applescript variable, but it's not working through the conventional method.

I have a list that looks something like [Terminal, Utilities, Finder, Launchpad]. I pass the bash list into an applescript variable by stating:

```
set applescriptList to "$bashList"
```

This works with any other data structure I've tried to pass into an applescript variable via osascript However, when I log the first item in the list, instead of returning Terminal in this example, it would return the letter "T". Similarly, if I log the second item, it returns the letter "e" instead of Utilities, so it seems each individual character is an item in the list.

Does anybody have any experience passing a bash list into an applescript variable? Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting the bash array to be an array or string in AppleScript?  How are you building the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this:

```
bashList=(Terminal Utilities Finder Launchpad)
```

then you can do this:

```
osascript -e "set ASlist to the paragraphs of \"$(printf '%s\n' "${bashList[@]}")\""
```

or, somewhat simpler to read given all the quotes that need escaping above:

```
osascript <<OSA
    set ASlist to the paragraphs of "$(printf '%s\n' "${bashList[@]}")"
OSA
```

Although, if you know that each item in your `bashList` consists only of a single word, then this negates the need for `printf`:

```
osascript <<OSA
    set ASlist to the words of "${bashList[@]}"
OSA
```

The result returned to `stdout` in bash after running any of these examples will look like this:

```
Terminal, Utilities, Finder, Launchpad
```

which is what I would expect.  The equivalent AppleScript output would have looked like this:

```
{Terminal, Utilities, Finder, Launchpad}
```

to indicate that `ASlist` had be assigned a list of values, denoted by the curly braces.  However, this list is poorly translated into bash output, so the curly braces get lost and it isn't easy to distinguish a list from a string containing a few commas.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'bash list' you mean multi-line text, in which case use `paragraphs of bashList` to split it at line breaks.